# How to run PyTorch on GPU by default?

Tags: python, pytorch

I want to run PyTorch using cuda. I set `model.cuda()` and `torch.cuda.LongTensor()` for all tensors.

Do I have to create tensors using `.cuda` explicitly if I have used `model.cuda()`?

Is there a way to make all computations run on GPU by default?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I do not think you can specify that you want to use cuda tensors by default.
However you should have a look to the pytorch offical examples.

In the imagenet training/testing script, they use a wrapper over the model called [DataParallel](https://github.com/pytorch/examples/blob/master/imagenet/main.py#L72).
This wrapper has two advantages:

- it handles the data parallelism over multiple GPUs
- it handles the casting of cpu tensors to cuda tensors

As you can see in [L164](https://github.com/pytorch/examples/blob/master/imagenet/main.py#L164), you don't have to cast manually your inputs/targets to cuda.

Note that, if you have multiple GPUs and you want to use a single one, launch any python/pytorch scripts with the CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES prefix. For instance `CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=0 python main.py`.

Comment: They are on line 294 and 296

Answer (score 5):

You can use [set_default_device](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.set_default_device.html).

For Nvidia GPU:

```
torch.set_default_device('cuda')
```

If you have multiple GPUs, you can select a specific one:

```
torch.set_default_device('cuda:1')
```

For CPU use `'cpu'`

```
torch.set_default_device('cpu')
```

You can check default device by creating a simple tensor and getting its device type: `torch.tensor([1.2, 3.4]).device` would return `device(type='cuda', index=0)` if the first GPU is selected.

---

You can also wrap your code with [device](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/tensor_attributes.html?highlight=device#torch.device):

```
with torch.device('cuda:0'):
    t = torch.tensor([1.2, 3.4])
```

In this case default will only be changed for the wrapped code.

Comment: Note that torch.set_default_device() only works on latest pytorch versions (2.0+) and won't work on old versions.

Comment: @KenvixZure Does that mean it works on 2.0, too, or only on versions >2.0?

Answer (score 4):

Yes. You can [set the default tensor type](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/how-to-create-a-tensor-on-gpu-as-default/2128) to cuda with:

```py
torch.set_default_tensor_type('torch.cuda.FloatTensor')
```

> Do I have to create tensors using .cuda explicitly if I have used model.cuda()?

Yes, you need to not only set your model [parameter] tensors to cuda, but also those of the data features and targets (and any other tensors used by the model).