# If I'm not specifying to use CPU/GPU, which one is my script using?

Tags: python, pytorch

In pytorch, if I'm not writing anything about using CPU/GPU, and my machine supports CUDA (`torch.cuda.is_available() == True`):

1. What is my script using, CPU or GPU?
2. If CPU, what should I do to make it run on GPU? Do I need to rewrite everything?
3. If GPU, will this script crash if `torch.cuda.is_available() == False`?
4. Does this do anything about making the training faster?
5. I'm aware of [Porting PyTorch code from CPU to GPU](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46704352/porting-pytorch-code-from-cpu-to-gpu?rq=1) but this is old. Does this situation change in v0.4 or the upcoming v1.0?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to run PyTorch on GPU by default?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43806326/how-to-run-pytorch-on-gpu-by-default)

Comment: I think I was asking quite a different question, regarding implicit behavior on `torch` (which can be roughly described as "what would happen if no explicit call to `torch.set_default_tensor_type()` is done" but I'm not even sure whether this API exists in <0.4.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My way is like this (below pytorch 0.4):

```
dtype = torch.cuda.float if torch.cuda.is_available() else torch.float
torch.zeros(2, 2, dtype=dtype)
```

***UPDATE*** pytorch 0.4:

```
device = torch.device("cuda" if use_cuda else "cpu")
model = MyRNN().to(device)
```

from [PyTorch 0.4.0 Migration Guide](https://pytorch.org/2018/04/22/0_4_0-migration-guide.html).

Comment: I see, this is why so many people "`typedef`" in their models.

Comment: `dtype = torch.cuda.float if torch.cuda.is_available() else torch.float`
`AttributeError: module 'torch.cuda' has no attribute 'float'` What should I do? I'm using v0.4

Comment: @Ria, Does MyRNN() refers to the custom class which you have created?

Answer (score 7):

PyTorch defaults to the CPU, unless you use the `.cuda()` methods on your models and the `torch.cuda.XTensor` variants of PyTorch's tensors.

Answer (score 6):

> 1. **What is my script using, CPU or GPU?**

The "script" does not have any device alegiance. Where computations are done (CPU or GPU) depends on the specific tensor being operated on. Hence it depends on how the tensor was created.

However the default location for the `torch.tensor` function to create tensors *is* set to `'cpu'`:

```py
torch.FloatTensor()         # CPU tensor
torch.cuda.FloatTensor()    # GPU tensor

torch.tensor(device='cpu')  # CPU tensor
torch.tensor(device='cuda') # GPU tensor

torch.tensor([1,2])         # CPU tensor  <--
```

---

> 2. **If CPU, what should I do to make it run on GPU?**

You can [change the default type](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/how-to-create-a-tensor-on-gpu-as-default/2128) of each newly created `torch.tensor` with:

```py
# Approach 1
torch.set_default_tensor_type('torch.cuda.FloatTensor')
```

Or you can manually copy each tensor to the GPU:

```
# Approach 2
device = "cuda" if torch.cuda.is_availble() else "cpu"

my_tensor = my_tensor.to(device)
my_model.to(device) # Operates in place for model parameters
```

---

> 3. **If GPU, will this script crash if `torch.cuda.is_available() == False`?**

Yes, in Approach 1 the script would crash with the following error:

```py
RuntimeError: No CUDA GPUs are available
```

In approach 2 it will simply default to CPU.

---

> 4. **Does this do anything about making the training faster?**

[That depends.](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/cpu-x10-faster-than-gpu-recommendations-for-gpu-implementation-speed-up/54980) For most common PyTorch neural net training scenarios yes speed will be improved by moving to the GPU.

---

> 5. **I'm aware of Porting PyTorch code from CPU to GPU but this is old. Does this situation change in v0.4 or the upcoming v1.0?**

There are a number of ways to port code from CPU to GPU:

```py
# Syntax 1
my_tensor = my_tensor.cuda()

# Syntax 2
device = 'cuda' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu'
my_tensor = my_tensor.to(device)
```

Syntax 2 is often preferred for allowing a switch between CPU and GPU by changing one variable.

Comment: Changing the the default type (approach #1) was a live saver for me - where struggling the last hours for finding a solution to add a '.cuda()' to the torch.tensor depending on gpu/cpu. Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 2):

You should write your code so that it will use GPU processing if `torch.cuda.is_available == True`:

```
if torch.cuda.is_available():
    model.cuda()
else:
    # Do Nothing. Run as CPU.
```

Answer (score 0):

It will use the default one. You can change default GPU to 1 using the following code before making your model :

```
import torch as th
th.cuda.set_device(1)
```

Comment: Are 0 shorthand for `cpu` in this case? What about `cuda:0` and `cuda:1` if I have more than 1 gpu?

Answer (score 0):

> What is my script using, CPU or GPU?

By default all tensors are allocated on the CPU.

---

> If CPU, what should I do to make it run on GPU? Do I need to rewrite everything?

You can use [set_default_device](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.set_default_device.html) to change the default device.

For Nvidia GPU:

```
torch.set_default_device('cuda')
```

If you have multiple GPUs, you can select a specific one:

```
torch.set_default_device('cuda:1')
```

For CPU use `'cpu'`

```
torch.set_default_device('cpu')
```

You can check default device by creating a simple tensor and getting its device type: `torch.tensor([1.2, 3.4]).device` would return `device(type='cuda', index=0)` if the first GPU is selected.

---

You can also wrap your code with [device](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/tensor_attributes.html?highlight=device#torch.device):

```
with torch.device('cuda:0'):
    t = torch.tensor([1.2, 3.4])
```

In this case default will only be changed for the wrapped code.

---

> If GPU, will this script crash if torch.cuda.is_available() == False?

`torch.set_default_device` and `torch.device` allow selecting non-existing device but creating tensors would then fail with an exception.