# Code example in Hugging Face Pytorch-Transformers quickstart documentation

Tags: python, nlp, pytorch, huggingface-transformers

I am following the quick start guide [here](https://huggingface.co/pytorch-transformers/quickstart.html). The problem is they have provided code for GPU machine and I am running the code on CPU based Ubuntu machine. I have commented the lines that put everything in CUDA. The code is now showing error and I don't know how to resolve it.
The question is "How can I make this work?"

I have checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50495053/if-im-not-specifying-to-use-cpu-gpu-which-one-is-my-script-using) answer and this is not what I'm looking for.

The full code is [here](https://huggingface.co/pytorch-transformers/quickstart.html#bert-example)

1. Using BertModel to encode inputs in hidden-states:

```
#Load pre-trained model (weights)
model = BertModel.from_pretrained('bert-base-uncased')

#Set the model in evaluation mode to desactivate the DropOut modules
# This is IMPORTANT to have reproducible results during evaluation!
model.eval()

#***I have commented these 3 lines*** 

# If you have a GPU, put everything on cuda
#tokens_tensor = tokens_tensor.to('cuda')
#segments_tensors = segments_tensors.to('cuda')
#model.to('cuda')

#Rest all is untouched
# *** -----------------***---------------***

# Predict hidden states features for each layer
with torch.no_grad():
    # See the models docstrings for the detail of the inputs
    outputs = model(tokens_tensor, token_type_ids=segments_tensors)
 # PyTorch-Transformers models always output tuples.
 # See the models docstrings for the detail of all the outputs
 # In our case, the first element is the hidden state of the last layer of the Bert model
    encoded_layers = outputs[0]
# We have encoded our input sequence in a FloatTensor of shape (batch size, sequence length, model hidden dimension)
assert tuple(encoded_layers.shape) == (1, len(indexed_tokens), model.config.hidden_size)
```

Error for 1:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-40-a86e9643e7f3> in <module>
     11 
     12 # We have encoded our input sequence in a FloatTensor of shape (batch size, sequence length, model hidden dimension)
---> 13 assert tuple(encoded_layers).shape == (1, len(indexed_tokens), model.config.hidden_size)

AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'shape'
```

## 2. Using BertForMaskedLM to predict a masked token:

```
# Load pre-trained model (weights)
model = BertForMaskedLM.from_pretrained('bert-base-uncased')
model.eval()

#***---------------Commented--------------------------
# If you have a GPU, put everything on cuda
#tokens_tensor = tokens_tensor.to('cuda')
#segments_tensors = segments_tensors.to('cuda')
#model.to('cuda')

#***---------------------------------------------

# Predict all tokens
with torch.no_grad():
    outputs = model(tokens_tensor, token_type_ids=segments_tensors)
    predictions = outputs[0]

# confirm we were able to predict 'henson'
predicted_index = torch.argmax(predictions[0, masked_index]).item()
predicted_token = tokenizer.convert_ids_to_tokens([predicted_index])[0]
assert predicted_token == 'henson'
```

Error for 2:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AssertionError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-42-9b965490d278> in <module>
     17 predicted_index = torch.argmax(predictions[0, masked_index]).item()
     18 predicted_token = tokenizer.convert_ids_to_tokens([predicted_index])[0]
---> 19 assert predicted_token == 'henson'

AssertionError:
```

Comment: Your code is working perfectly for me. I am running pytorch version 1.1.0 on a Windows machine with python 3.6.  May be upgrading to the latest version of `pytorch_transformers` would do the trick.

Comment: I installed it just before this quick start guide that I followed, print(torch.__version__) gives me this:  1.2.0+cu92

Comment: both the errors have nothing to do with CUDA/CPU.

Comment: I agree. It was to give context to the problem. What I want to know is "why this error?" and "how can I resolve it?".

Comment: Any luck here? Face the same problem here