# Using CUDA with pytorch?

Tags: python, pytorch

Is there a way to reliably enable CUDA on the whole model?

---

I want to run the training on my GPU. I found on some forums that I need to apply `.cuda()` on anything I want to use CUDA with (I've applied it to everything I could without making the program crash). Surprisingly, this makes the training even slower.

Then, I found that you could use this `torch.set_default_tensor_type('torch.cuda.FloatTensor')` to use CUDA. With both enabled, nothing changes. What is happening?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [If I'm not specifying to use CPU/GPU, which one is my script using?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50495053/if-im-not-specifying-to-use-cpu-gpu-which-one-is-my-script-using)

Comment: `MyModel()` is presumably just an example variable name for the model being used in the code.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to run PyTorch on GPU by default?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43806326/how-to-run-pytorch-on-gpu-by-default)

Answer (score 84, accepted):

You can use the [`tensor.to(device)`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/tensors.html?highlight=#torch.Tensor.to) command to move a tensor to a device.

The [`.to()`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html?highlight=#torch.nn.Module.to) command is also used to move a whole model to a device, like in the post you linked to.

Another possibility is to set the device of a tensor during creation using the `device=` keyword argument, like in `t = torch.tensor(some_list, device=device)`

To set the device dynamically in your code, you can use

```
device = torch.device("cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")
```

to set cuda as your device if possible.

There are various code examples on [PyTorch Tutorials](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/index.html) and in the documentation linked above that could help you.

Comment: When calling `tensor.to(device)`, for the `device` argument you can use 'cpu', 'cuda', 'cuda:0', 'cuda:1', etc.  'cuda' and 'cuda:0' mean the same thing in most circumstances.  Click on the PyTorch tab within [Section 5.6.1](https://d2l.ai/chapter_deep-learning-computation/use-gpu.html#computing-devices) of d2l.ai for more details.

Comment: You can check if a tensor is located on the GPU by printing `tensor.device`.

Answer (score 3):

> With both enabled, nothing changes.

That is because you have already set every tensor to GPU.

> Is there a way to reliably enable CUDA on the whole model?

```
model.to('cuda')
```

> I've applied it to everything I could

You only need to apply it to tensors the model will be interacting with, generally:

- the model's pramaters `model.to('cuda')`
- the features data `features = features.to('cuda')`
- the target data `targets = targets.to('cuda')`