# Pytorch device and .to(device) method

Tags: pytorch

I'm trying to learn RNN and Pytorch.

So I saw some codes for RNN where in the forward probagation method, they did a check like this:

```
def forward(self, inputs, hidden):
    if inputs.is_cuda:
        device = inputs.get_device()
    else:
        device = torch.device("cpu")
    embed_out = self.embeddings(inputs)
    logits = torch.zeros(self.seq_len, self.batch_size, self.vocab_size).to(device)
```

I think the point of the check is to see if we can run the code on faster GPU instead of CPU?
To understand the code a bit more, I did the following:

```
ex= torch.zeros(3,10,5)
ex1= torch.tensor(np.array([[0,0,0,1,0], [1,0,0,0,0],[0,1,0,0,0]]))

print(ex)
print("device is")
print(ex1.get_device())
print(ex.to(ex1.get_device()))
```

And the output was:

```
        ...
        [[0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
         [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
         [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
         [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
         [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
         [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
         [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
         [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
         [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
         [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]]])
device is
-1
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-b09342e2ba0f> in <module>()
     67 print("device is")
     68 print(ex1.get_device())
---> 69 print(ex.to(ex1.get_device()))

RuntimeError: Device index must not be negative
```

I don't understand the "device" in the code and I don't understand the `.to(device)` method. Can you help me understand it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using CUDA with pytorch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50954479/using-cuda-with-pytorch)

Comment: Do you have a GPU ? Can you tell me the output of the command `torch.cuda.is_available()` ?

Answer (score 2):

This code is deprecated. Just do:

```
def forward(self, inputs, hidden):
    embed_out = self.embeddings(inputs)
    logits = torch.zeros((self.seq_len, self.batch_size, self.vocab_size), device=inputs.device)
```

Note that `to(device)` is cost-free if the tensor is already on the requested device. And do not use `get_device()` but rather `device` attribute. It is working fine with cpu and gpu out of the box.

Also, note that `torch.tensor(np.array(...))` is a bad practice for several reasons. First, to convert numpy array to torch tensor either use `as_tensor` or `from_numpy`. THen, you will get a tensor with default numpy dtype instead of torch. In this case it is the same (int64), but for float it would be different. Finally, `torch.tensor` can be initialized using a list, just as numpy array, so you can get rid of numpy completely and call torch directly.